# Swift associated type conforming with multiple optional protocols

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-protocols, associated-types

While I am dealing with generics, I get stuck with protocols of the associated type.
Basically, what I want to achieve in here, I want to think "ReusableView", "NibLoadableView" as optional and I don't want to comform my class if these will not be used.

For example, if I only use "ReusableView" to comform, it will throw an error

> 'ExampleBannerPresenter' does not conform to protocol 'BannerPresenter'

So how can I manage to use my cells like below?

```
final class ExampleBannerCell: UICollectionViewCell, ReusableView {

final class ExampleBannerCell: UICollectionViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView {
```

Here is my code

```
public protocol BannerPresenter: class {
    associatedtype CellType: UICollectionViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView
    func configure(cell: CellType, at index: Int)
}

// MARK: - NibLoadableView
public protocol NibLoadableView: class {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

extension NibLoadableView where Self: UIView {
    public static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

// MARK: - ReusableView
public protocol ReusableView: class {
    static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension ReusableView where Self: UIView {
    public static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This happens because you constrained your associated type to be always of type `UICollectionViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView`, so if your cell class doesn't satisfy all requirements, the presenter itself doesn't. Show the the `ExampleBannerPresenter` implementation, so we can help you refactor your structure

Comment: Yes, I know that is the thing but I want to cover this some how. There is nothing special on ExampleBannerPresenter. It use "func configure(cell: CellType, at index: Int)" and obviously it takes "ExampleBannerCell" as cell and because of associated type it expects (UICollectionViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView). But is there any way to work and compile if I don't add NibLoadableView?

Comment: Why don't you do `associatedtype CellType: UICollectionViewCell` without any other constraint?

Comment: Because of; for some cell, I want to use attributes of "NibLoadableView" and 
 another "ReusableView". If you don't declare these protocol on your custom UICollectionViewCell its fine, because CellType also covers UICollectionViewCell.